# Fastest way to find difference between image pixel and palette colour in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, optimization

I am working on some code for converting an image to the palette of the NES. My current code is somewhat successful, but very very slow.

I am doing it by using Pythagoras' theorem. I'm using the RGB colour values as coordinates in 3D space and doing it that way. The colour in the palette with the smallest distance from the pixel's RGB is the colour that gets used.

```
class image_filter():
    def load(self,path):
        self.i = Image.open(path)
        self.i = self.i.convert("RGB")
        self.pix = self.i.load()

    def colour_filter(self,colours=NES):
        start = time.time()
        for y in range(self.i.size[1]):
            for x in range(self.i.size[0]):
                pixel = list(self.pix[x,y])
                distances = []
                for colour in colours:
                    distance = ((colour[0]-pixel[0])**2)+((colour[1]-pixel[1])**2)+((colour[2]-pixel[2])**2)
                    distances.append(distance)
                pixel = colours[distances.index(sorted(distances,key=lambda x:x)[0])]
                self.pix[x,y] = tuple(pixel)
        print "Took "+str(time.time()-start)+" seconds."

f = image_filter()
f.load("C:\\path\\to\\image.png")
f.colour_filter()
f.i.save("C:\\path\\to\\new\\image.png")
```

Using the list:

```
NES = [(124,124,124),(0,0,252),
           (0,0,188),(68,40,188),
           (148,0,132),(168,0,32),
           (168,16,0),(136,20,0),
           (80,48,0),(0,120,0),
           (0,104,0),(0,88,0),
           (0,64,88),(0,0,0),
           (188,188,188),(0,120,248),
           (0,88,248),(104,68,252),
           (216,0,204),(228,0,88),
           (248,56,0),(228,92,16),
           (172,124,0),(0,184,0),
           (0,168,0),(0,168,68),
           (0,136,136),(248,248,248),
           (60,188,252),(104,136,252),
           (152,120,248),
           (248,120,248),(248,88,152),
           (248,120,88),(252,160,68),
           (184,248,24),(88,216,84),
           (88,248,152),(0,232,216),
           (120,120,120),(252,252,252),(164,228,252),
           (184,184,248),(216,184,248),
           (248,184,248),(248,164,192),
           (240,208,176),(252,224,168),
           (248,216,120),(216,248,120),
           (184,248,184),(184,248,216),
           (0,252,252),(216,216,216)]
```

This produces the following Input:

[image: img]

and Output:

[image: img]

This takes between 14 and 20 seconds, which is much too long for its intended application. Does anyone know of any ways to greatly speed this up?

As an idea, I was thinking it may be possible to use numpy arrays for this; however I am not at all familiar enough with numpy arrays to be able to pull it off.

If possible, I would also like to try avoiding using scipy -- I know that, at least under Windows, it can be a pain to install and would prefer to steer clear.

Comment: This is going to be hard to test without the full code. Is it prohibitively long? I see multiple things going on here, three nested for loops, append operations being called over an over, sorting and finally its not C

Comment: @MS-DDOS That is pretty much the full code. I think the probably the only thing referenced that's needed and not provided is the 'NES' list. I'll add that now.

Comment: Thanks that should help. But I'm really curious about the member data such as `self.i` and `self.pix`, what are their types? Are you using any library or is this just pure python?

Comment: @MS-DDOS I have edited the post to show the code for loading the image in. I'm using PIL (Pillow) currently for loading in the images.

Comment: You could organize your points in an octree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962775/how-to-efficiently-find-k-nearest-neighbours-in-high-dimensional-data

Comment: see related QAs: [Effective gif/image color quantization?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) and [Converting BMP image to set of instructions for a plotter?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** We could use [`Scipy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) to get the euclidean distances and then look for the min distance arg and thus select the appropriate colour.

Thus, with NumPy arrays as the inputs, we would have an implementation like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

out = colours[cdist(pix.reshape(-1,3),colours).argmin(1)].reshape(pix.shape)
```

---

**Approach #2 :** Here's another approach with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = pix - colours[:,None,None]
out = colours[np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ijk',subs,subs).argmin(0)]
```

---

**Interfacing between PIL/lists and NumPy arrays**

To accept images read through PIL, use :

```
pix = np.asarray(Image.open('input_filename'))
```

To Use `colours` as array :

```
colours = np.asarray(NES)

# .... Use one of the listed approaches and get out as output array
```

To output the image :

```
i = Image.fromarray(out.astype('uint8'),'RGB')
i.save("output_filename")
```

Sample input, output using given colour palette `NES`  -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you think of any methods that don't involve scipy? I know it's a pain to install.

Comment: Regarding approach #2 -- looking into broadcasting, this seems like a good plan. In what way will I need the image to be inputted to use this method? Currently I am storing it as a PIL RGB Image. I will add the current code for loading in the image for you to see.

Comment: @WORD_559 Guess you could do : `np.asarray(PIL.Image.open('pic1.jpg'))` to get `pix`as NumPy array, where `pic1.jpg` is the input filename and for `colours`: colours = np.asarray(NES)?

Comment: `colours` is just an array containing the RGB values of the NES's palette. Would `np.asarray(NES)` work with your code or would I have to modify it a bit more?

Comment: @WORD_559 Yes `np.asarray(NES)` for `colours` should work.

Comment: How would I then convert the numpy array back into a PIL Image? I have tried `i = Image.fromarray(out,'RGB')` but that just produces noise. Sorry, I've never really used numpy arrays before, especially not with images.

Comment: I've uploaded the output of `i = Image.fromarray(out,'RGB')` to [here](http://i.imgur.com/hxZ7RKd.png)

Comment: @WORD_559 Use `Image.fromarray(out.astype('uint8'),'RGB')`. Added a section on those interfacing issues.

Comment: Nevermind! Got it! `i = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(self.numpy_out))` seems to do the job fine. Thanks so much for your help, marking as answer.